# Iterate over XML in Django Temnplate

Tags: python, html, xml, django, django-templates

I have a block of XML that is returned from an API call.

It contains lots of results - person elements like below.

```
<root><person><name>mark</name><age>18</age></person><person><name>alan</name><age>10</age></person></root>
```

I want to pass this data structure (or some iterable version if it) to a django template to iterate over.

In my template I want to say

```
{% for r in results %}
{{ r.name }}
{{ r.age }}
{% endfor %}
```

I thought this would have been straight forward but its posing problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django templates cannot handle it out-of-the-box. And it doesn't actually sound correct - to pass an XML structure into HTML template to process.

Making custom template tags or filters that would help to iterate over the XML structure could be a possible solution, but in this case you may find yourself overcomplicating things, template layer was made for presentation, [don't put too much logic into it](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/misc/design-philosophies/):

> We see a template system as a tool that controls presentation and
>   presentation-related logic – and that’s it. The template system
>   shouldn’t support functionality that goes beyond this basic goal.

Parse the XML in the view, make a list of dictionaries and pass it to the template inside the context.

For example, use [`xmltodict`](https://github.com/martinblech/xmltodict) tool:

```
persons = xmltodict.parse(data)['root']['person']
```

where `data` is your XML structure.

Comment: fair enough, looks like i have to do this. was hoping there would be something out of the box to support this. It would be nice.